# Keep state in decorator

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a @assert_logged_in decorator.

On paper, it's easy:

```py
def assert_logged_in(meth: Callable):
    logged_in = False
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not logged_in:
            try:
                test_login()
            except as err: # bare except only for this example
                raise NotLoggedIn from err

        logged_in = True # <= that is what I do not understand ‽‽‽

        return meth(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

# somewhere else
@assert_logged_in
def do_something(self):
    pass
```

As long as I do not try to update `logged_in`, the code runs, but would test loggedinness every time.

If I try to update `logged_in` as in my example, I receive: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'logged_in' referenced before assignment`. Even if I try to use `global`. Note that I do not want to keep the state in self (which works), because this decorator will be used across multiple classes.

I am very confused because this example:

```
def memoize(f):
    memo = {}
    def memoized_func(n):
        if n not in memo:            
            memo[n] = f(n)
        return memo[n]
    return memoized_func
```

does work as intended and keeps state.

There is obviously something I do not understand. What could it be, and how could I get my decorator working?

Comment: In the first example you try to re-assign **another** value to `logged_in`. In the second example you try to update a key of the **same** `memo` dict. These are not the same.

Comment: It doesn't look like you even need `logged_in`. If an exception is not raised it can be assumed that `logged_in` is `True`

Comment: if you really want a state, make `logged_in` a dict and modify a key `'login_status'` as well as probably more things in it?

Comment: @DeepSpace Technically True about the exception, but this decorator will be liberally used, and I want to have it do the heavy lifting (`test_login()`) only once.

Comment: @PatrickArtner that sound like an easy workaround indeed. But why could I not update a variable directly?

Comment: dicts are references .. True / False are ints, id(True) != id (False) - references work different from ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, there are 2 options:

**Cleanest option:**

Declare `logged_in` normally outside the wrapper, and then again as `nonlocal` inside the wrapper.

**Other possibility**

- from a wrapper, you cannot not change an external variable
- but if this variable happens to be a reference (dict, collections...) then the wrapper can update its content without changing its reference.

For instance, have a dict instead of a boolean:

```
logged_in = {"logged_in": False}
```

instead of

```
logged_in = False
```

Anotherj comment five

Comment: you can change the external variable if  you first declare it with the "nonlocal" keyword within the wrapper function, i.e the first line should be "nonlocal logged_in"

Comment: @Siracle this is awesome and exactly what I was looking for! Feel free to make an answer out of it, and I'll delete mine.